# How to get a handle to a new Object while unit testing?

Tags: java

How would I test this ValueObject created on the fly in SomeClass without stubbing it out using PowerMock etc?

```
class ValueOBject {
    private String x, y;
    getters
    setters
}
class SomeClass {
    public void  foo () {
       ValueObject vo = new ValueObject();
       vo.setX("some string 1");
       vo.setY("some string 2");

       faa(vo);
    }

    public void faa(ValueObject vo) {
        // do some more logic on vo here
    }
}


class SomeClassTest extends TestCase{
   public void testFoo() {
       SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
       s.foo();
       // HOW TO DO THIS?
       verify(faa(VAlueObject that is created during foo's run));
   }
}
```

I dont want to use PowerMockito  or similar libraries to return a MOCKED object!
Rather a REAL object thats created during execution of the method foo() :

```
//    DONT WANT A MOCKED OBJECT
//    @Mock
//    private ValueOBject vo;
//     henNew(GetEmailInformation.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(getEmailInformation);
```

Comment: Would an accessor be helpful?

Answer (score 1):

The ValueObject is created internally, so it can only depend on object state. You don't need to test internals, you only need to test the side effects of the calls you do.

In this case you don't need to test foo because you know what foo does, it's only a wrapper for faa.  Thus, you need to test faa for actions and side effects caused by the global state and the ValueObject input.

If you want to test the foo() does what you expect, you have to test that the side effects that foo() causes are the same that faa(expectedObject) has.

In other words: if foo and faa are public, and the public interface says that foo is a wrapper for faa with a fixed parameter, you need to test that foo does exactly what faa does with the fixed parameter you expect.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you want to assert against the ValueObject created in `foo()` and passed to `faa(vo)`?

Create a unit test instantiates the expected ValueObject and passes it to `faa(vo)`. Then compare the results of this to the results that occur when you just call `foo()`.

For example:

```
// in your unit test:
ValueObject testVo = new ValueObject();
// set values as needed
// testVo should represent what you expect the ValueObject instantiated by foo to 
// hold *before* it gets passed to faa

faa(testVo);
// assertions against results of faa method

foo();
// assertions *comparing* the results of foo with the results of your manual faa
```

So for example, if I expect `foo` to create a ValueObject with X=1 and Y=1, and then for `faa` to do magic on them such that the ValueObject's end result is X=-1 and Y=2, your unit test will look something like this:

```
ValueObject testVo = new ValueObject();
testVo.setX(1);
testVo.setY(1);

faa(testVo);
// assertions using your testing library of choice to verify getX() returns -1 and
// getY() returns 2

foo();
// assertions that the end values after foo()'s faa call are -1 and 2 respectively
```

Now in your dummy examples above, both `foo` and `faa` are void methods, so there's no returned value. I am assuming that `faa` actually *does* something that is testable -- eg. sets fields, changes values, and so on.

In some comments you left on other answers, you made a note that you have some private and/or protected fields and methods involved. If this is the case, you'll want to look into [Java reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/) for how to retrieve those values.

But for specifically ripping out the ValueObject instantiated within `foo()` before it is passed to `faa(vo)`, this is impossible. As I described above, your best bet is to test your expectations of behavior for the ValueObject you *expect* to be created in `foo()` and comparing the results of it being passed to `faa(vo)` with what actually does happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is telling you that the design has tight coupling so  maybe  inject the object into the method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider testing `faa()` with in `foo()`. From an OOP standpoint, I would rather the caller of `foo()` never need to know `faa()` even existed. Does `faa()` need to be public?

Comment: specifically - both faa and foo are protected

Comment: After looking at your code more I'm a little confused. `faa()` and `foo()` both return void and you don't store `vo` within `SomeClass`. As far as I can tell, it is impossible for anyone to get `vo` (this even includes `SomeClass` because it doesn't store the object. Do you want to createe `vo` within the test class and pass it to `foo()`? It looks to me like you are losing `vo` when `foo()` returns. (it will be deleted by the garbage collector.)